# Как правильно пользоваться опциональными типами данных в условных операторах и циклах в Swift?

Tags: swift

Почему компилируется такой код:

```
while var text = readLine()
{
    //тело цикла
}
```

И не компилируется такой:

```
while (var text = readLine())
{
    //тело цикла
}
```

Но при этом так все работает

```
while (true)
{
    //тело цикла
}
```

В чем разница? Также еще непонятно, почему нельзя использовать такую конструкцию:

```
while var text = readLine() && true
{
    //тело цикла
}
```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста код функци readLine()

Comment: Это стандартная функция, которая читает данные с консоли, и возвращает "String?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно авторы языка, стремясь к ясности и однозначности, разграничили в конструкции с `while` операции сравнения и присваивания.

То есть, используя *только* `while`, вы либо осуществляете присваивание переменной в цикле (при этом проверка на `nil` производится автоматически и не может быть произведена явно)

```
while var text = readLine()
{
    //тело цикла
}
```

Либо осуществляете проверку на `nil`

```
while (readLine() != nil)
{
    //тело цикла
}
```

Если вы хотите использовать сложные условия с присваиванием, то предлагается использовать специальную конструкцию `while case`, тогда ваше условие можно переписать так (и да, здесь будет бесконечный цикл)

```
while case var text = readLine(), true
{
    //тело цикла
}
```